# Need help on adsense account

Tags: adsense

I'm trying to create my google account adsense and I stuck at this point

[image: Adsense Site]

Do I need to get marked on the second line?

I just need to wait?

The code is on my website: www.codando.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Place the ad code on your website.
2. Wait for it to be activated, if I remember correctly this took round 48 hours for me... While you are waiting the adsense part of the site will just appear white.

Answer (score 2):

You need to click the big blue button, which will guide you through the steps of placing your ad code on your site.

If you've already done that, you just need to wait.